# How can I get large title to collapse in React Native with `headerTransparent` enabled?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I'm trying to render a list in React Native. I would also like to use `headerLargeTitle` with a blurred background. However, when using `headerTransparent` the large header does not collapse as it does when `headerTransparent` is disabled.

In order to implement the blur effect, you need to enable `headerTransparent`. This moves the list under the header, so I used `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"` to account for that.

This looks correct before you start scrolling, but once scrolling begins the large title does not collapse as it should. This sort of makes sense, logically, but I can't see any other approach. Can the large title + blurred background effect be achieved at all?